# How can I ignore all JOINS, PARTS from all but a few channels?

Tags: irc, irssi

On the `freenode` network I want to ignore ALL joins, parts EXCEPT in channels `#foo` and `#bar`.

What would be the syntax for this?

I tried:

```
/ignore -except #foo, #bar JOINS PARTS QUITS
```

I also tried to read the /help ignore but it's quite confusing. Also, would i just `/save` to keep it permanent?

Comment: The configuration is saved whenever you use `/save` or `/quit`.

Comment: For the buggy version of qwebirc that is used on http://irc.lc/ , where clicking on the 3 stripes button at the upper left corner does not open its menu, I can tell that an user can type `/options` , then there the Options page becomes accessible, where there is a checkbox for `Hide JOINS/PARTS/QUITS`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/ignore -except #foo,#bar * JOINS PARTS QUITS
```

I don't know if it mathers but don't place a space after the `,` and the internet shows me a * is needed.

Comment: I can still see people leaving in other channels, even after `/save` and then `/reload`, hrm..

Comment: Ok, I did.. `/ignore * JOINS PARTS QUITS` and then `/ignore -except #foo,#django,#css JOINS PARTS QUITS`. Seems to work.

Comment: Ah, sounds like you have to ignore everything before you can except channels, well, nice that you got this working. Joins and parts are indeed annoying in very big channels, but they are very valuable in small rooms with your friends. :-)