# How can I get notified by everything that happens in a specific channel in irssi?

Tags: irc, irssi

(Be it hilight/highlight or a beep). I have a small channel that I need to know all the info of. I couldn't get trigger.pl to work, but maybe it should. I could do "/hilight -mask every_single_nick" but that's not efficient enough (nor the Right Way).

edit:

Figured out a shaky solution. Have:

/set beep_msg_level ALL

/set bell_beeps ON

be enabled, but do /ignore -except #foo ALL

It prevents nick hilight sounds from other channels but it will work for me.

from: [How can I ignore all JOINS, PARTS from all but a few channels?](https://superuser.com/questions/164855/how-can-i-ignore-all-joins-parts-from-all-but-a-few-channels?rq=1)

Comment: `on *:ACTION:*:# { beep }`  and `on *:TEXT:*:# { beep }` solves the issue?

Comment: As its own Perl script? I'm not too familiar with Perl, but I guess I could learn.

Comment: its IRC script actually, dunno if it applies to your case

Comment: I'm interested in irssi; would that be relevant?

Comment: if it has some sort of way to call a standart IRC script, yes it would.

Comment: @Znau I believe those commands are mIRC specific, and based off of TCL.. I know they work on mIRC, but I could be wrong about the specific part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download this: https://scripts.irssi.org/scripts/opnotify.pl

Type this:

```
/script load [pathtoscript]
/notify-on [nick]
```

Full list of scripts: [Click](https://scripts.irssi.org/)