# Irssi won't /ignore -except #channel QUITS

Tags: irc, irssi

In irssi, I prefer to ignore joins, parts, quits globally.

However there are a few channels in which I'd like to see even these messages.

I followed the instructions on [How can I ignore all JOINS, PARTS from all but a few channels?](https://superuser.com/questions/164855/how-can-i-ignore-all-joins-parts-from-all-but-a-few-channels)

They work brilliantly for joins and parts, but I don't see quits.

```
/ignore * JOINS PARTS QUITS
Ignoring JOINS PARTS QUITS from *
/ignore -except #channel JOINS PARTS QUITS
Ignoring JOINS PARTS QUITS from #channel [-except]
/ignore
Ignore List:
   1 *: JOINS PARTS QUITS
   2 #channel: JOINS PARTS QUITS -except
```

When I use a second client to join #channel I see:

```
 -!- user [nick@domain] has joined #channel
```

Then if I /part the second client I see:

```
 -!- user [nick@domain] has left #channel
```

But if I just quit the second client I don't see a quit message.

If I /unignore 1 to remove the global ignore rule, I see all messages again.

Is this an irssi bug, an irc bug, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

That's most probably caused because `QUIT` events are global to the network, and not to a specific channel. When you use `/quit`, you're not leaving a channel, you're quitting the whole network, that's why it doesn't match the second rule you have added.

You can either ignore them all or see them all (although it might be supported if the `irssi` team decides to implement this as an enhancement).

Comment: So it is an irssi bug where they don't apply -except rules to server wide messages? I thought the server propagated the quit to the channel? Otherwise you would never se any quits?

Comment: I'm not sure if calling it a bug is right here, more likely I'd say that's the *default* behavior in terms of the IRC protocol. Processing the quit event and showing it in your common channels is an additional feature that IRC client programmers must implement additionally, as that's not something relative to channels but to the global network instead, that's why I called it an "enhancement" instead of a bug. But you can give it a try and request this to be implemented as a feature if they haven't done so yet (in that case it might be a bug).